# In what episode of TOS did a character on the bridge make a comment about raising the number 1 to some power?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, episode-identification

Long, long ago, I was watching an episode of TOS when a character usually or often on the bridge of the *Enterprise* made a comment about **raising the number 1 [sic] to some power**.

I don't remember who it was, or what point he was endeavoring to make -- I do remember that the comment was not ironic -- but it sure was a low point in *Star Trek* for me.  That I just groaned and continued to watch says multitudes about the addictive power of *Star Trek*.

Who said this, and in what context?  (Actually, after so many decades, I can't be 100% positive it was in TOS.)

Comment: **SCOTT:** *Scotty, sir. We have a reading on the power source Mister Spock requested. When we first monitored, it was generating alternating cycles totalling one hundred to the twentieth power Waltham units.* - TOS: The Apple

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## "Court Martial" ([*TOS* 1x15](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Court_Martial_(episode)))

Kirk is facing a court martial.  In his defense, the *Enterprise* crew are trying to find someone hiding aboard the ship.

From the [transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/15.htm):

> **KIRK:** Gentlemen, this computer has an auditory sensor. It can, in effect, hear sounds. By installing a booster, we can increase that capability on the order of **one to the fourth power**. The computer should bring us every sound occurring on the ship.

Kirk says the line in this video clip, starting at the 55-second mark:

Comment: He could conceivably be saying that it will boat the signal somewhere between doubling it and quadrupling it. But that's a charitable, non-mathematical interpretation.

Comment: What I want to know is how Gaultheria came up with this within a few minutes of my posting the question.  And it was only a few minutes, not a hour.  Was this an unforgettable trauma for him/her too?

Comment: @ab2 — I think that Kirk *tries* to be serious, but Spock was right there and couldn't interrupt to correct him.  (I didn't remember the exact reference, but a Google search for `trek kirk "one" "power" site:chakoteya.net` brought it up.)

Comment: So obviously mathematical language has changed a little since the 20th century.

Comment: I'm surprised by the fuss about this. It's simply 1E04, or 1*(10^4). He's just talking scientific notation in short form.

Comment: I think Behrens' interpretation makes the most sense to me, but these are all plausible; I think I'd say "one to the fourth power" as "x^(1..4)" or "1e4" would be a misspeak if ever said seriously, but it's the sort of mistake a tired or distracted mathematician could really make.

Comment: I don't think it quite makes sense for kirk to have made this mistake in context, but if he were explicitly drunk or someone called him on it, it'd make total sense.

Comment: It was a busy day; Kirk was distracted. A friend betrays Kirk and tries to ruin his career, Kirk's old flame is prosecuting him, Kirk turns the tables on his friend, the friend's daughter gets caught in the crossfire... All this would have been playing through Kirk's mind at the same time as he had to give that technical explanation.

Comment: "Gentlemen, that sound is caused by the heartbeats of all the people on board the ship"  - This sounds more like 1E04 than quadrupling the sound.

Comment: @motoDrizzt Saying "one to the fourth power" as a shortened form of the number 1E4 would be like saying "eight" as a shortened form of the number 38. (The actual shortened form would be "ten to the fourth", or just "ten thousand".) One can easily retcon why Kirk would have misspoken, but you can't seriously argue that it wasn't a mistake.

Comment: Or perhaps by "increase it (*x*) by 1 to the fourth power" he means "Somewhere between *2x* (increase *x* by *x*) and *x^4* (increase it to the fourth power)?

Comment: Of course, the simpler explanation was that it was a mistake, just how people make mistakes and say things like "uh" all the time, but you can't show real speech on TV because of time and that fact that it annoys the audience.

Comment: The real question is how somebody wrote it, somebody went over the draft of the script, Shatner was saying it across multiple takes in the presence of multiple cast and crew, and at no point did anyone go "wait a sec..."

Comment: @Gaultheria For future reference, there's an app for that (searching chakoteya.net): http://scriptsearch.dxdy.name/

Comment: @Galastel Was it actually in the script?  It's possible the script had something similar (like 10 to the fourth) and he happened to misspeak it in the take they used.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian To expand on your point, people should also remember that at the time TOS was filmed, film was expensive. Each extra take would cost money. It would have to be an extremely egregious mistake for a director to justify redoing the scene if everything else about the take went flawlessly.

Comment: Maybe somewhere between capability^1 and capability^4....hopefully closer to the latter or they've wasted a bit of time with the whole booster installation business.